# Spliting all three attributes of this list

Tags: django, python-3.x, split

`[8352] Marilyn Hudson - 16000 Views`

This is the instance that I get from FacebookAdsAPi
I have been trying a separate list into 3 attributes separately.

I have used 
`client.split("]")[1]`

But it gives me `Marilyn Hudson - 16000 Views`. How can i get all three attributes seperately?
Expected output -

```
              id >> 8352
              name >> Marilyn Hudson
              impressions >> 16000
```

TIA

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar how can i get all three attributes seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
In [1912]: client
Out[1912]: '[8352] Marilyn Hudson - 16000 Views'

In [1930]: new_list.append(re.findall(r'\d+', client.split('-')[0])[0])

In [1931]: new_list.append(client.split('-')[0].split('] ')[1].strip())

In [1932]: new_list.append(client.split('-')[1].strip())

In [1933]: new_list
Out[1933]: ['8352', 'Marilyn Hudson', '16000 Views']
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: in our last split method for views i just need the number, which i have acheived using other regex but in some cases the data is like this - `[8352] Marilyn Hudson - 499 for 16000 Views`. So i just need to get 16000 but with your method i get 499. Can you help me?

Comment: Sure. Considering `s = '[8352] Marilyn Hudson - 499 for 16000 Views'` to be your string. Use this `s.split('for')[1].strip()`. This will yield `'16000 Views'`. Ideally, you should post this as a separate question. And I should get some points for answering it. :)

Comment: It works, i'll post it as a question and accept your answer. thnks